# Customizing Rally using Rally app builder

Tags: rally, code-rally

Trying to customize Portfolio Item Burnup , got source code from https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/rpm/burn

Now after compiling using "rally-app-builder build" command and after that running with "rally-app-builder run" command, I am able to run the page. In another tab of chrome, Rally is logged in. the launched page is getting authentication from rally session and able to get some data like searching some PFG/PF etc. 
Now problem is after applying some settings and selecting some PF/PFG, its again demands authentication (for rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize). This authentication is not working with my credential.

I have also generated some api key from rally1.rallydev.com/login/accounts/index.html#/keys ,but, that also not working.

Pls help on this.

Thanks,
Udayan

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you use SSO to login?  If so, you won't be able to correctly authenticate against that /security/authorize endpoint (which is used for generating a CSRF token when making POST/PUT/DELETE calls against wsapi- GETS are fine).

You were on the right track with the api key.  Generate a key and then just add it to the query string of your app url:

```
http://localhost:1337/App-debug.html?apiKey=83h3lkb4b43302bfvlav
```

There's also a guide in the App SDK docs that describes this in greater detail: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps